# CellCache renders unexpectedly in TableView with tornadoFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, kotlin, tornadofx

I just puzzled by the `cellCache` funtion usage in `TornadoFX` with `Kotlin`. The render is always strange and unexpected, what happens with that? The code is here:

```
data class Person(var name : String, var age : Int, var sex : Boolean)

class MyView: View()
{
    val list = listOf<Person>(
            Person("Name A", 20, false),
            Person("Name B", 22, false),
            Person("Name C", 21, true),
            Person("Name D", 30, true),
            Person("Name E", 35, true)
    ).observable()

    override val root = stackpane {

        vbox {
            tableview(items = list) {
                column("Name", Person::name)
                column("Age", Person::age)
                column("Sex", Person::sex).cellCache{
                    checkbox{
                        isSelected = it
                        setOnAction {
                            println("Selection: $isSelected")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect all the rows will render with a `checkbox` in column `"Sex"`, but the code above will just display two: one `selected` and another `unselected`, what the hell is going on with `cellcache`?
I also find changing the `data class` with the one below, and it is all right:

```
data class Person(var name : String, var age : Int, var sex : SimpleBooleanProperty)
```

However I must change a lot with the data class properties in this way, I also don't know why.
Help me, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the last code of Person class should not use data class but just common class prefix. this works: `class Person(var name : String, var age : Int, sex : Boolean)
{
    var sex by property(SimpleBooleanProperty(sex))
    fun sexProperty() = getProperty(Person::sex)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cellCache` creates a unique cell per item in your list. If your items does not implement meaningful `equals` and `hashCode` functions you will run into trouble with `cellCache` since the same cell will be used for multiple underlying items.

Adding `equals` and `hashCode` implementation that ensures each item is unique should solve the problem. It seems that the default implementation in a Kotlin data class doesn't cut it :)

If you can't or won't provide `equals` and `hashCode` implementations I would suggest using `cellFormat` instead, which doesn't rely on object equality to produce a unique cell.

I'm sorry this isn't made clear in the guide, I will update the TableView part with more information and a warning about the use of `cellCache`.

Comment: Thanks very much, and I should test that in my code right now.

Comment: Thanks, `cellFormat` works for me! `graphic = checkbox {
                        isSelected = it
                        setOnAction {
                            println("Selection: $isSelected")
                        }
                    }`